# 16 bit adder using 2 bit adder as component

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I am trying to create a 16-bit adder using 2-bit adders as components (which themselves use 1-bit adder as component). However, my code doesn't compile in Quartus II. Can someone help me please? Thank you very much!

My project is consisted of 3 files: bit_adder.vhd, add2.vhd and add16.vhd. The error happens in add16.vhd:

```
--- bit_adder.vhd
-- description of 1 bit adder
LIBRARY IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity BIT_ADDER is
        port( a, b, cin         : in  STD_LOGIC;
              sum, cout         : out STD_LOGIC );
end BIT_ADDER;

architecture BHV of BIT_ADDER is
begin

        sum <=  (not a and not b and cin) or
                        (not a and b and not cin) or
                        (a and not b and not cin) or
                        (a and b and cin);

        cout <= (not a and b and cin) or
                        (a and not b and cin) or
                        (a and b and not cin) or
                        (a and b and cin);
end BHV;
```

-- below is add2.vhd, a 2-bit Adder. adds two 2-bit numbers together using two 1-bit adders

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity add2 is
    port( a, b      : in    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
          ans       : out   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
          cout      : out   STD_LOGIC       );
end add2;

architecture STRUCTURE of add2 is

-- Component: two 1-bit adders

component BIT_ADDER
    port( a, b, cin     : in  STD_LOGIC;
          sum, cout     : out STD_LOGIC );
end component;

signal c0, c1 : STD_LOGIC;
begin

c0 <= '0';
b_adder0: BIT_ADDER port map (a(0), b(0), c0, ans(0), c1);
b_adder1: BIT_ADDER port map (a(1), b(1), c1, ans(1), cout);

END STRUCTURE;
```

-- add16.vhd
-- set as top level entity

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity add16 is
    port (a, b : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
            sum1 : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
            cout : out std_logic_VECTOR(1 downto 0)); --_vector);
end add16;

architecture arch16 of add16 is
    component BIT_ADDER 
        port( a, b, cin         : in  STD_LOGIC;
              sum, cout         : out STD_LOGIC );
    end component;

    component add2
        port (a, b      : in    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
          ans       : out   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
          cout      : out   STD_LOGIC       );
    end component;

    signal c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7  : std_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
    begin
    c0 <='00'; --Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at add16.vhd(26) near text "'";  expecting "(", or an identifier, or  unary operator

    D_adder0: add2 port map (a(0), b(0), c0, sum1(0), c1);
    D_adder1: add2 port map (a(1), b(1), c0, sum1(1), c2);
    D_adder2: add2 port map (a(2), b(2), c0, sum1(2), c3);
    D_adder3: add2 port map (a(3), b(3), c0, sum1(3), c4);
    D_adder4: add2 port map (a(4), b(4), c0, sum1(4), c5);
    D_adder5: add2 port map (a(5), b(5), c0, sum1(5), c6);
    D_adder6: add2 port map (a(6), b(6), c0, sum1(6), c7);
    D_adder7: add2 port map (a(7), b(7), c0, sum1(7), cout);
    end arch16;
```

Comment: Thanks @eugene-sh but there are 3 more errors in add16.vhd. This one is in the port map section: Error (10381): VHDL Type Mismatch error at add16.vhd(28): indexed name returns a value whose type does not match "std_logic_vector", the type of the target expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The modules `add2` and `add16` must have a `cin` port, Why don't you add it to your design? If you want to get the correct result all the modules must have "carry in". The technique you used is `Carry Ripple Adder`, then in `add16` each block (instance) must have a `cin` port that is provided from the previous block.

2) In the module `add16` why the signals `c1`, `c2`, ... are 2 bits? Each block needs a `cin` port that is 1 bit. Also you don't need the signal`c0`, because in the module `add16`, `c0` is the same `cin`.

3) In the module `add16` why the ports of each instance (`a`,`b`,`sum1`) is 1 bit. It must be 2 bits.

4) In the module `add16` you don't need the component `BIT_ADDER`. You can remove it.

I edited your code with the above changes. I simulated it and could get the correct result in Modelsim. (I didn't change the module `BIT_ADDER`) :

```
------------------------------- add2 ---------------------------------
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;


ENTITY add2 IS
    PORT( a, b  : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
          cin   : IN  STD_LOGIC;
          ans   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
          cout  : OUT STD_LOGIC
    );
END add2;

ARCHITECTURE STRUCTURE OF add2 IS

    COMPONENT BIT_ADDER
        PORT( a, b, cin  : IN  STD_LOGIC;
                sum, cout  : OUT STD_LOGIC
        );
    END COMPONENT;

    SIGNAL c1 : STD_LOGIC;

BEGIN

    b_adder0: BIT_ADDER PORT MAP (a(0), b(0), cin, ans(0), c1);
    b_adder1: BIT_ADDER PORT MAP (a(1), b(1), c1, ans(1), cout);

END STRUCTURE;



------------------------------- add16 ---------------------------------
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY add16 is
    PORT (  a, b : IN  std_logic_vector(15 DOWNTO 0);
            cin  : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            sum1 : OUT std_logic_vector(15 DOWNTO 0);
            cout : OUT std_logic);
END add16;

ARCHITECTURE arch16 OF add16 IS

    COMPONENT add2
        PORT(  a, b      : IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
               cin       : IN    STD_LOGIC;
               ans       : OUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
               cout      : OUT   STD_LOGIC);
    END COMPONENT;

    SIGNAL c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7  : std_LOGIC;

BEGIN

    D_adder0: add2 PORT MAP ( a(1  DOWNTO 0)  , b(1 DOWNTO 0)  , cin, sum1(1 DOWNTO 0)   , c1  );
    D_adder1: add2 PORT MAP ( a(3  DOWNTO 2)  , b(3 DOWNTO 2)  , c1 , sum1(3 DOWNTO 2)   , c2  );
    D_adder2: add2 PORT MAP ( a(5  DOWNTO 4)  , b(5 DOWNTO 4)  , c2 , sum1(5 DOWNTO 4)   , c3  );
    D_adder3: add2 PORT MAP ( a(7  DOWNTO 6)  , b(7 DOWNTO 6)  , c3 , sum1(7 DOWNTO 6)   , c4  );
    D_adder4: add2 PORT MAP ( a(9  DOWNTO 8)  , b(9 DOWNTO 8)  , c4 , sum1(9 DOWNTO 8)   , c5  );
    D_adder5: add2 PORT MAP ( a(11 DOWNTO 10) , b(11 DOWNTO 10), c5 , sum1(11 DOWNTO 10) , c6  );
    D_adder6: add2 PORT MAP ( a(13 DOWNTO 12) , b(13 DOWNTO 12), c6 , sum1(13 DOWNTO 12) , c7  );
    D_adder7: add2 PORT MAP ( a(15 DOWNTO 14) , b(15 DOWNTO 14), c7 , sum1(15 DOWNTO 14) , cout);

END arch16;
```

Answer (score 0):

The vector literals in VHDL are put into double quotes, i.e. `"00"`, not `'00'` 
**Update**: In the `port map` section you are assigning single bit signals to double bit inputs:

```
 D_adder0: add2 port map (a(0), b(0), c0, sum1(0), c1);
```

Here, for example, `a(0)` is a lowest bit of `a`. But your `add2` component is expecting a signal of width 2:

```
 component add2
        port (a, b : in    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0); -- <-- 2bits wide
        ans       : out   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
        cout      : out   STD_LOGIC       );
    end component;
```